# Looped reversed sum of business days based on groups in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with various groups of orders in a column. Each order group has several processes, each with its own lead time. For the last process of each order group, I have the finish date (and start date, because lead time is always zero for final process).

Now for each preceding process of each order group, I need to calculate the start and finish date. The finish date of a process always equals the start date of the next process (unless next process is new order group). The lead time represents business days, hence start dates should always be on a business day.

My DataFrame is structured as below:

```
Order   Process    LeadTime   Start         Finish
01      A          3          NaT           NaT
01      B          5          NaT           NaT
01      C          0          2023-11-30    2023-11-30
02      D          2          NaT           NaT
02      E          0          2023-12-13    2023-11-13
03      F          1          NaT           NaT
03      G          1          NaT           NaT
03      H          6          NaT           NaT
03      I          0          2023-11-21    2023-11-21
...     ...        ...        ...     ...
```

Required Output:

```
Order   Process    LeadTime   Start         Finish
01      A          3          2023-11-20    2023-11-23
01      B          5          2023-11-23    2023-11-30
01      C          0          2023-11-30    2023-11-30
02      D          2          2023-12-08    2023-12-12
02      E          0          2023-12-12    2023-12-12
03      F          1          2023-11-09    2023-11-10
03      G          1          2023-11-10    2023-11-13
03      H          6          2023-11-13    2023-11-21
03      I          0          2023-11-21    2023-11-21
...     ...        ...        ...     ...
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tested the solution below?

Comment: Yes and it works for this question, but not for my new question. It overwrites existing Start values if a group already has a few more start values, other than only the start value in the last row.

Comment: So it's your only issue? Then simply replace the NaNs (see update to my answer)

Comment: That is my only issue but the answer is not that simple. Because with your solution, the backwards cumulative calculation still starts with the second to last row. Hence, in the example data of my previous question, the start dates to be calculated end up to be way to early in time, because the LT of the rows with already a start date is set at 0. It should not start the calculation at the second to but with the last row that is NaN. And this is different for every group.

Comment: Then maybe open a new question but link to this one and clearly explain how this differs. Also craft your example to show a non-trivial case.

Comment: I have highlighted it into my other question (which is now closed??), but tbh it was already clear from the example data that I shared. Not sure how to link to other questions though.

Comment: I saw your other question, it's clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute a reverse [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) of LeadTime, convert to [`BusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay.html) offset, then subtract this from your reference dates (propagated with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
cols = ['Start', 'Finish']

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)

s = (df.loc[::-1, 'LeadTime']
       .groupby(df['Order']).cumsum()
       .apply(pd.offsets.BusinessDay)
    )
g = df.groupby('Order')

for c in cols:
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime(g[c].transform('first').sub(s))
```

Output:

```
   Order Process  LeadTime      Start     Finish
0      1       A         3 2023-11-20 2023-11-20
1      1       B         5 2023-11-23 2023-11-23
2      1       C         0 2023-11-30 2023-11-30
3      2       D         2 2023-12-11 2023-11-09
4      2       E         0 2023-12-13 2023-11-13
5      3       F         1 2023-11-09 2023-11-09
6      3       G         1 2023-11-10 2023-11-10
7      3       H         6 2023-11-13 2023-11-13
8      3       I         0 2023-11-21 2023-11-21
```

##### replacing only NaNs

If you don't want to affect existing values, change the last loop to:

```
for c in cols:
    m = df[c].notna()
    df.loc[m, c] = pd.to_datetime(g[c].transform('first').sub(s))[m]
```

Comment: Yes thanks, this worked for the example as I shared.