# Grouped reversed cumulative date calculation with dynamic start

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**The specific difference with my previous question is:**

- Previous question: start date for calculation was always the last row of a group.
- Previous question: [Looped reversed sum of business days based on groups in Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77501989/looped-reversed-sum-of-business-days-based-on-groups-in-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment137650891_77501989)
- Current question: start date for calculation is first row within a group that is not NaN.

I have a dataframe as below:

```
   Group    LT         Start
0      A     5           NaT
1      A    10           NaT
2      A     0    20-03-2024
3      B     3           NaT
4      B     0    04-03-2024
5      C     2           NaT
6      C     4           NaT
7      C     0    04-04-2024
8      C     0    10-04-2024
9      C     0    24-04-2024
```

For each group as defined in `Group` I need to calculate the `Start` value of each row:

- Using the first row within a group with a value in `Start` as start point for calculation. (in example data: index=2, index=4, index=7)
- Ignoring all dates within a group after this start date
- Backwards scheduling, from bottom to top.
- Values in `LT` represent business days, weekends should be skipped.
- Repeat for every group.

Hence, the required output is:

```
   Group    LT         Start
0      A     5    28-02-2024
1      A    10    06-03-2024
2      A     0    20-03-2024
3      B     3    28-02-2024
4      B     0    04-03-2024
5      C     2    27-03-2024
6      C     4    29-03-2024
7      C     0    04-04-2024
8      C     0    10-04-2024
9      C     0    24-04-2024
```

The following code works for the majority (it correctly selects the first row in each group with a date value as start date), but I fail to make it work with business days only:

```
groups = df.groupby('Group')
nan_start_mask = df['Start'].isna()
df['Start'] = groups['Start'].bfill()
start_date = df['Start'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['LT'], unit='D')
df.loc[nan_start_mask, 'Start'] = start_date[nan_start_mask]
```

The next code originates from my linked question, which handles the business days fine, but always takes the last row of each group as starting point:

```
s = (df.loc[::-1, LT'].groupby(df['Group']).cumsum().apply(pd.offsets.BusinessDay))
g = df.groupby('Group')
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(g['Start'].transform('first').sub(s))
```

So for group C, the wrong output of this second code would be:

```
5      C     2    16-04-2024
6      C     4    18-04-2024
7      C     0    24-04-2024
8      C     0    24-04-2024
9      C     0    24-04-2024
```

Any suggestions on how to include the business day functionality of the second code into the dynamic start row functionality of the first code?

Comment: Are the 0s always in the end of a group? Can you have a group with 1,2,0,1,0 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the previous approach this way:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True)

# for a group in reverse order
g = df[::-1].groupby('Group')

# identify NaNs
m = df['Start'].isna()

# backfill the dates (ffill since we inverted the frame)
# subtract the cumulated day offset
# only update the NaNs
df.loc[m, 'Start'] = (g['Start'].ffill()
                      .sub(g['LT'].cumsum().mul(pd.offsets.BusinessDay()))[m]
                     )
```

Output:

```
  Group  LT      Start
0     A   5 2024-02-28
1     A  10 2024-03-06
2     A   0 2024-03-20
3     B   3 2024-02-28
4     B   0 2024-03-04
5     C   2 2024-03-27
6     C   4 2024-03-29
7     C   0 2024-04-04
8     C   0 2024-04-10
9     C   0 2024-04-24
```

Comment: Yes that worked very well, thanks. You were right with your comment on my question, only works when end of groups are all 0s. In my complete data that is not the case, but I work around it by temporarily setting them to 0 and then copying in the 'LT' column from before this analysis.

Answer (score 2):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
         'LT': [5, 10, 0, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
         'Start': ['NaT', 'NaT', '20-03-2024', 'NaT', '04-03-2024', 'NaT', 'NaT', '04-04-2024', '10-04-2024', '24-04-2024']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

---

**Code**

at first make datetime

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], errors='coerce', format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

I have slightly modified your previous answer(@mozway). For reference, the variable `grp` is a grouper created in your example because 0 appears multiple times in the same group. This was done in case there are NaTs between 0 and 0 within a group.

```
s = df['LT'].eq(0)
grp = s.groupby(df['Group']).cumsum() - s

s1 = (df.loc[::-1, 'LT']
      .groupby([df['Group'], grp]).cumsum()
      .apply(pd.offsets.BusinessDay)
)

out = (df
       .groupby(['Group', grp])['Start'].transform('first')
       .sub(s1).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
)
```

out:

```
0    28-02-2024
1    06-03-2024
2    20-03-2024
3    28-02-2024
4    04-03-2024
5    27-03-2024
6    29-03-2024
7    04-04-2024
8    10-04-2024
9    24-04-2024
```

Modify your column with the variable `out`.